# Platform or system

Tags: word-choice

We are writing a product sheet. Our product enables to play a 360 video. We deliver the application and the content too.

Currently we are arguing which word describing our solution suits the best: a **platform** or a **system**?

How do you feel it as a native speaker?

Answer (score 1):

Many words will emphasise different aspects:

- It's a **product** because you made it: "It's taken a year to *develop our product*."
- If you can build on top of it, then it's also a **platform**.  "You can build anything from a security system to a quality assurance system *on our platform*."
- If it's made of pieces which operate together, it's also a **system**.  "The cameras work perfectly with the network and storage *elements of our system*."
- If it solves someone's problem, it's also a **solution**.  "Buy our product, the ideal *solution to the problem* of joining X to Y."